# Query on deploying local network

Tags: solidity, dapps, hardhat, smart-contract

I am following Patrik Collin's solidity course where he is deployed the smart contract first in local network then in testnet. My question is deploying in local network is necessary?

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary, yet normally can help you iterate fast if are some bugs, you can deploy very quickly locally, and for testnet you need test Eth and it sometimes takes a while.